# SSID empty but ip available in WifiInfo on some android phones

Tags: android

Some of the users of my app complain about the connection between computer and device can not be made. My app makes tcp connection from computer to android phone.

So getting the log from users about their phone the WifiInfo object's to String method returns info but SSID is missing. but IP is assigned (on some users phones) - in the following string before supplicat state , SSID should be mentioned which it does in most cases but not in some cases.

```
    WifiInfio : , Supplicant state: COMPLETED, RSSI: -73, Link speed: 52, Net ID: 1, Metered hint: false, mFrequency: 2412 - IP:192.168.165.244
```

I get WifiInfo using code below and then call toString() on it

```
     WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    return wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

Any ideas why SSID could be empty and still have ip address in the wifi info ?

Comment: The connection is not currently connected??? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID%28%29

Comment: No, I can confirm connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected() returns true at the time when I have the above output

Comment: is it NULL or is it returning non printable characters?